# How to use increment to count something over a certain price

Tags: php, html, conditional-statements

I have a hw question that asks me to count the number of soups over $2 if somebody was to enter them in. My professor hinted that I should use incrementing to count the number of soups over $2. My code for PHP is below. I am very new to PHP and my professor is very poor at giving examples, instruction, and being a teacher. Any help will be great!

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
 <title>Cafe</title>
<style type="text/css" media="screen"> .error { color: red; } </style>
</head>

 <body>

 <?php
$monday = $_POST['monday'];
$tuesday = $_POST['tuesday'];
$wednesday = $_POST['wednesday'];
$thursday = $_POST['thursday'];
$friday = $_POST['friday'];
$monday_item = $_POST['monday_item'];
$tuesday_item = $_POST['tuesday_item'];
$wednesday_item = $_POST['wednesday_item'];
$thursday_item = $_POST['thursday_item'];
$friday_item = $_POST['friday_item'];
$m_price = $_POST['m_price'];
$t_price = $_POST['t_price'];
$w_price = $_POST['w_price'];
$th_price = $_POST['th_price'];
$f_price = $_POST['f_price'];
$total = ($m_price + $t_price + $w_price + $th_price + $f_price);


if( empty ($_POST['tuesday']))
{print '<p class="error"> You did not complete all of the required fields</p>';
$okay = FALSE;
}

if ( !is_numeric ($_POST['th_price']))
{print '<p class="error"> That is not a number </p>';
$okay = FALSE;
}

if ($_POST['m_price'] > 10)
{print '<p class="error"> That is too Much!!! </p>';
}

if($total > 10):
echo "total is greater than 10";
elseif($total == $b): // Note the combination of the words.
echo "total equals 10";
else:
echo "total is less than 10";
endif;

if ($_POST['m_price'] > 2)
{print }



print
"<table border='1'>";
print "<tr>
                    <td> $monday </td>
                    <td> $monday_item </td>
                    <td> $m_price </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                        <td> $tuesday </td>
                        <td> $tuesday_item </td>
                        <td> $t_price </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                        <td> $wednesday </td>
                        <td> $wednesday_item </td>
                        <td> $w_price </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                        <td> $thursday </td>
                        <td> $thursday_item</td>
                        <td> $th_price </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                        <td> $friday </td>
                        <td> $friday_item </td>
                        <td> $f_price </td>
            </tr>";
        print   "</table>";

    print "<p> Your total price of soups is $total </p>";

    ?>


  </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: First things first, if it's for every day of the week, you should make an array for each item in the HTML so you would have the ability to loop over that array for the count, total, etc. ie `price[]` for the `name` in the HTML, or `price[1]` to index them yourself. ^^

Comment: Where is your code that checks if the price is > 2?

Comment: @Barmar - I guess... if ($_POST['m_price'] > 2)

Comment: `elseif($total == $b)` where is `$b` being defined?  From the echo following this conditional statement, `($total ==10)` would be more accurate.

Comment: Right, so just add that to your script, and do it for each day.

Comment: @Jon Array would be better but could be too complicated at this point in time until he gets a little further in the studies.

Comment: I do not have the code that checks if the price is >2. I am just really confused

Comment: Eesh.  Been a while since I went to school for programming, but arrays are a part of _everything_ related to PHP and getting data from the use (ie `$_POST` and `$_GET`).  It should be one of the first things you learn about, and moving it to HTML constructs should be the natural evolution.  This code is the antithesis of efficient/clean - my opinion has always been if your going to learn, learn the correct way so you don't have to unlearn what you already know.  Just my humble opinion though. ^^

Comment: I attempted to start with the if ($_POST['m_price'] > 2) but then didn't know where to go from there

Comment: Is $monday_item like number of soups on monday?

Comment: items is the kind of soup you want that day. It is supposed to be a menu or something the teacher doesn't explain that day. then price is the price of that soup

Comment: Since each day can have a different price that the soup is. You can have a $1 on one day then maybe it is $10 on wednesday. So counting the number of days it is over $2

Comment: @user2309048 - look at my answer. Does it make any sense to you?

Comment: honestly i learn best with examples and then interpreting it to my problem. So your answer is kind of confusing to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Start creating a variable with number 0. like $nrsoups = 0;
- Increase that value (variable $nrsoups) with one when price is larger
  then two for a certain day
- Nr of soups over 2 dollars = $nrsoups

Something like:

```
$nrsoups = 0;
if ($_POST['m_price'] > 2) $nrsoups++;
if ($_POST['t_price'] > 2) $nrsoups++;
```

etc...